# `require` in VSCode extension: Cannot find module './tool.js'

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, commonjs

I'm trying to write a language server based off of the [vscode languages server sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/lsp-sample).

I have a file at `lsp-sample/server/src/tool.js` which was generated by an external tool (js_of_ocaml), which I'd like to import in my plugin using `require`. I do this as follows in `lsp-sample/server/src/server.ts`:

```
var tool = require('./tool.js');
```

However, when I do so, I get the following rutime error:

```
Cannot find module './tool.js'
```

If I `require` using an absolute path, I don't get an error, but obviously that doesn't work for an extension that I'd like to run on multiple computers.

What is the proper path I should be giving to `require`? What is the "current directory" that I need to define my relative path in relation to?

Answer (score 0):

When using require(), you should not include the file extension. Try

```
var tool = require('./tool');
```

instead.